# Java Driver License Program - Having trouble displaying which problems I missed

Tags: java

I created my program according to the instructions below. When I run my program, my output for the incorrect answers that I missed is incorrect. For example, if I input all the correct answers but #19, it would say 1 or 2 in the incorrect answers section of the output data. What did I do wrong?

---

The local Driver's License Office has asked you to write a program that grades the written portion of the license exam. The exam has 20 multiple choice questions. A student must correctly answer 15 questions of the 20 questions to pass the exam. Here are the correct answers:

```
1. B    2. D    3. A    4. A
5. C    6. A    7. B    8. A
9. C    10. D   11.B    12. C
13. D   14. A   15. D   16. C
17. C   18. B   19. D   20. A

Input validation: only accept the letters A, B, C, or D as answers
```

Here is my output data:

```
    Driver's License Exam 
 20 Multiple-Choice Questions 
       Mark A, B, C, D   
1: B
2: D
3: A
4: A
5: C
6: A
7: B
8: A
9: C
10: D
11: B
12: C
13: D
14: A
15: D
16: C
17: C
18: B
19: D
20: C
  RESULTS  
Total Correct: 19
Total Incorrect: 1
Passed: YES
The incorrect answers are: 
 2
```

---

```
public class DriverExam
{
   //An array containing a student's answers
   private String[] correctAnswers = 
                                 {"B", "D", "A", "A", "C", "A", 
                                  "B", "A", "C", "D", 
                                  "B", "C", "D", "A", 
                                  "D", "C", "C", "B", "D", "A"}; 
                                  
   //Store the user's answers
   private String[] userAnswers; 
   int[] missed = new int[correctAnswers.length]; 
   
   //Process the user's answers
   public DriverExam (String[] Answers)
   {
      userAnswers = new String[Answers.length]; 
      
      for (int i = 0; i < Answers.length; i++)
      {
         userAnswers[i] = Answers[i]; 
      }
   }
   
   //Returns a boolean value if correct answers > 15 
   public boolean passed()
   {
      if (totalCorrect() >= 15)
         return true; 
      else
         return false; 
   }
   
   //Determines the total correct answers
   public int totalCorrect()
   {
      int correctCount = 0; 
      
      for (int i = 0; i < correctAnswers.length; i++)
      {
         if (userAnswers[i].equalsIgnoreCase(correctAnswers[i]))
         {
            correctCount++; 


            }
          }
          return correctCount; 
       }
       
       //Determines the total incorrect answers
       public int totalIncorrect()
       {
          int incorrectCount = 0; 
          
          for (int i = 0; i < correctAnswers.length; i++)
          {
             if (!userAnswers[i].equalsIgnoreCase(correctAnswers[i]))
             {
                missed[incorrectCount] = 1; 
                incorrectCount++; 
             }
          }
          return incorrectCount; 
       }
    
       //Missed questions
       public int[] questionsMissed()
       {
          return missed; 
       }
       
    }
    //end of DriverExam class

----------------------------------------------------------------------------


import java.util.Scanner; 

public class DriverExamApplication
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      System.out.println("    Driver's License Exam "); 
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
      
      System.out.println(" 20 Multiple-Choice Questions "); 
      System.out.println("       Mark A, B, C, D   "); 
                                       
      //Inputting string
      String[] answers = new String[20]; 
      String answer; 
      
      for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
      {
         do
         {
            System.out.print((i+1) + ": "); 
            answer = input.nextLine(); 
         } while (!isValidAnswer(answer)); 
         
         answers[i] = answer; 
      }
      
      //Process
      DriverExam exam = new DriverExam(answers); 
      
      //Results
      System.out.println("  RESULTS  "); 
      
      //Outputting total correct
      System.out.println("Total Correct: " + exam.totalCorrect()); 
      
      //Outputting total incorrect
      System.out.println("Total Incorrect: " + exam.totalIncorrect()); 
      
      String passed = exam.passed() ? "YES" : "NO"; 
      
      //Result pass or fail
      System.out.println("Passed: " + passed); 
      
      if (exam.totalIncorrect() > 0)
      {
          System.out.println("The incorrect answers are: "); 
          
          int missedIndex; 
          
          for (int i = 0; i < exam.totalIncorrect(); i++)
          {
            missedIndex = exam.questionsMissed()[i]+1; 
            System.out.print(" " + missedIndex); 
          }
      }
   } //end of main function
   
   //Returns true when answer is valid
   public static boolean isValidAnswer (String answer)
   {
      return "A".equalsIgnoreCase(answer) || 
         "B".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)
         || "C".equalsIgnoreCase(answer) || 
         "D".equalsIgnoreCase(answer); 
   }
} //end of Test class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the function `totalIncorrect` where you always assign `1`instead of `i`. This should work:

```
   //Determines the total incorrect answers
   public int totalIncorrect()
   {
      int incorrectCount = 0; 

      for (int i = 0; i < correctAnswers.length; i++)
      {
         if (!userAnswers[i].equalsIgnoreCase(correctAnswers[i]))
         {
            missed[incorrectCount] = i; 
            incorrectCount++; 
         }
      }
      return incorrectCount; 
   }
```

Comment: Thank you! I completely over looked that part.